# Use matrix input for a custom QGIS processing plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I'm trying to create a custom processing tool inside my QGIS plugin. The goal is to have:

- An input for multiple layers (this is working)
- A **matrix** with a dimension of (nb_layer, nb_layer) that let me select a specific **distances between each layers**.

For example, I want to be able to select buildings, roads and rivers, and define a distance value between pair of layers, so I have:

- buildings-roads = 30m
- buildings-rivers = 15m
- roads-rivers = 2m.

I'm trying to test what the [QgsProcessingParameterMatrix](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsProcessingParameterMatrix.html) class from the QGIS API holds but I can't have it working. My current code for that parameter is:

```
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterMatrix(
        self.DISTANCES,
        self.tr('Distances'),
        hasFixedNumberRows=False
    )
)
```

This makes my QGIS crash and I can't find any resources besides the QGIS API to help me with my problem. So, maybe you can help me with this QGIS class, or maybe you have other ideas on how I can properly implement this feature in my QGIS plugin.